# How to auto populate fields using data from record in edit form using lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Once I click the edit button it will display the lightning page shown below. How can I make my component auto populated with data from the record that I am editing?

[image]

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where did you stuck? Can you update your question with these details? There are many people here to help you, but only if you provide a clear picture.

Comment: I am currently stuck finding a way to do this because I am not sure where to begin or if this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you override the standard edit button with a custom lightning component.

In your component, you can implement the interface:

> force:hasRecordId

This will give you the Id of the record that you are viewing. With this Id you can use Apex/Record Data to load the fields that you want and put it to the component.

Example (This code is used on the record page, but also works in a quick action):

yourComponent.cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String"  />    
<force:recordData aura:id="record"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  fields="Name"
                  targetFields="{!v.record}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
                  mode="EDIT"/>

<div class="Record Details">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Edit">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
            <lightning:input label="Name" value="{!v.record.Name}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:button label="Save Account" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveRecord}" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</div>

<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordSaveError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordSaveError}
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

yourComponentController.Js

```
handleSaveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("record").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {
        //Save result code here
    }));
}
```

Comment: I added a screenshot for better understanding of the question

Comment: @Newbee Thanks, you can use force:recordData in order to prepopulate the fields. For example: You have your custom edit component inside the case record page, so, with the interface force:hasRecordId you get the Id of the case, with record data, you can load the fields that you want and access with the v.record.fieldName.

Comment: just a follow up question does this work on all kinds of fields? Cause I have a lookup field and I am testing my page with a hard coded record id but the lookup is not pre-populated when I use the component in edit mode

Comment: Yes, you can use this approach to pre-populate lookup fields. For example: You have a custom component inside contact record page, wich allows yo to modify the contact related account. If you specify in record data the attribute fields with the field "AccountId" of contact, you can put the v.record.AccountId as value for a lightning:input. The only thing that you need to do its create a custom lookup component (You have very good examples in Internet, like the sfdcMonkey, wich I used so many times)

Comment: Without view the code behind, I think that you need to pass the value to "selectedRecord" attribute

Comment: I deleted my previous comment 
This is my code for the field and my code with the force:recordData is the same with what you did above and it is currently not working.

        <c:customLookup objectAPIName="Patient_Policy__c" value="{!v.record.Patient_Policy__c}" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}" label="Patient Policy"/>

Comment: "selectedReccord" attribute its Object type? If so, you need to pass the object reference. The force:RecordData approach will not work this time. You need to make a SOQL query in Apex in order to get the current record, and simply put it in the selectedRecord attribute. Maybe you need to make some modifications inside your "customLookup" component in order to accept a predefinied value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by "it is in classic once it is not in edit form."
Yes you can do that if you are in lightning. 
I have similar scenario where I have to open the record in edit form.

```
({
    edit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

You can call this method on any of your event and pass the recordId. It will open the record in "EDIT" mode with all the values populated.

Comment: I added a screenshot for better understanding